# Mapbox - How can I show buildings the way foursquare shows them?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Here's what I mean.

Take a look at the following screenshot from foursquare:

[image]

However, using street view, here's what that same area looks like in my map at the same zoom level:

[image]

As you can see, the buildings don't show up.  How can I make these buildings show up?

Answer (score 0):

If you use mapbox gl-js API than I might know the solution.
I think you need to add another layer, I did it like this(add the code below to your client-side javascritpt file):

```
`map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': '3d-buildings',
        'source': 'composite',
        'source-layer': 'building',
        'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'minzoom': 14,
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',
            'fill-extrusion-height': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-base': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'min_height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': .6
        }
    });
});`
```